# What is the name of this design pattern (exposing private method to collaborator via delegate)?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

What is the name for the design pattern where a class exposes a private method or property to a collaborator via a delegate? This is in C#, but may be relevant to other languages too.

For example:

```
class Foo
{
    public int X
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public void UpdateX(Bar bar)
    {
        bar.UpdateX(x => this.X = x);
    }
}

class Bar
{
    public void UpdateX(Action<int> setter)
    {
        setter(7);
    }
}

Foo foo = new Foo();
Bar bar = new Bar();
foo.UpdateX(bar);
```

I think this would be useful in the state pattern to allow states to update their contexts without requiring the context to expose stuff via its public interface, or nest state classes within the context class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't see any pattern here but its a break of encapsulation.

if you are having a readonly property so why you are trying circumvent it.

Comment: I think the idea here is to store the state of another object in Foo. It's a contrived example, sure.

Comment: Upon reflection, I tend to agree with this reply. I guess it's a coding idiom that doesn't qualify as a pattern. The encapsulation break would stem from the fact that client code could hang on to the delegate and change the property after the Update call has returned.

Answer (score 1):

[`Strategy Pattern`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) or [`State Pattern`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Delegation is a design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This has striking similarity to the Memento pattern, which is indeed useful for storing and manipulating states.

It also has elements of Dependency Injection or Delegation.

Perhaps someone more seasoned than I will recognize it by it's true name.

Here is some information on the Memento pattern:
[Wikipedia: Memento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern)

And the Dependency Injection pattern:
[Wikipedia: Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

Answer (score 0):

I'll take [Double Dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) for 200. And well on your way to the visitor pattern.

I would also argue that this doesn't break encapsulation, simply because Foo defines the delegate.